# Не работает код на wordpress, который отлично работает на локалке

Tags: wordpress, css3

Не работает именно эта часть css кода, ну и все что дальше. Еще добавил картинки, 1-я - как выходит на локалке,  2-я - как выходит на wordpress

```
.ac-container input[type=checkbox]:checked + label,
.ac-container input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:hover{
    background: #FFC0CB;
    color: #DB7093;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

вот полностью весь код

html

```
                 <section class="ac-container">
                      <div>
                          <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox"/>
                          <label for="ac-1">Поиск</label>
                          <article class="ac-small">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a class="ing" href="#">log1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ing" href="#">log2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ing" href="#">log3</a></li>
                                <li><a class="ing" href="#">log4</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </article>
                      </div>                
                </section>
```

css

```
    .ac-container label{
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #DB7093;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #FFC0CB;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFC0CB 1%, #FFC0CB 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#FFC0CB), color-stop(100%,#FFC0CB));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFC0CBf 1%,#FFC0CB 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFC0CB1%,#FFC0CB 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFC0CB 1%,#FFC0CB 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFC0CB 1%,#FFC0CB 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFC0CB', endColorstr='#FFC0CB',GradientType=0 );
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover{
    background: #FFC0CB;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
    background: #FFC0CB;
    color: #DB7093;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 13px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(/images/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center;    
}
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    background-image: url(/images/arrow_up.png);
}
.ac-container input{
    display: none;
}
.ac-container article{
    background: rgba(255,239,213, 0.5);
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container article p{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,239,213,0.8);
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article{
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
.container {
    background: url(images/bgnoise_lg.jpg);
    height: 500px;
}
```

[image: вообщем на локалке все выглядит так]

[image: вообщем на wordpress все выглядит так]

Comment: Что значит - на локалке? Она не на WordPress?

Comment: Да, сайт не на wordpress, и он работает. Проблема возникла, когда сайт начал переносить на wordpress